# Are my dates strings?

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, openoffice-base

I using Open Office to create an .odb database that is connected to an Access database, but I am having a hard time querying dates in the .odb database.

Here is an entry from the DATE column: ***02/11/13 12:00 AM***
(The column is actually called 'DATE')

How would I query this?

This is what I have tried:

**ERROR:Data type mismatch in criteria expression.**

```
SELECT *
FROM PHAII01 
WHERE DATE = '02/11/13 12:00 AM'
```

**ERROR: Syntac error (missing operator) in query expression 'DATE=02/11/13 12:AM'.**

```
SELECT *
FROM PHAII01 
WHERE DATE = 02/11/13 12:00 AM
```

**RETURNS NOTHING**

```
SELECT *
FROM PHAII01 
WHERE DATE = 02/11/13
```

**ERROR: Data type mismatch in criteria expression**

```
SELECT *
FROM PHAII01 
WHERE DATE = '02/11/13 12:00 AM'
```

**RETURNS NOTHING**

```
SELECT *
FROM PHAII01 
WHERE DATE = 2013/02/11
```

Comment: You'll need to be able to tell us what the actual column type is for the column. `DATE` is also a reserved word in most SQL dialects, so you may need to quote or escape it with `[]`. (Your question is also quite unclear about which database you're querying; the tags are for both MySQL and Access, and they're hardly the same thing and don't share the same data types or SQL syntax.)

Comment: @KenWhite, I have made the suggested changes. To clarify, I am querrying a SQL database.

Comment: Which tool do you use to query your database? And is your database still the Access database or do you moved your database to MySQL?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "SQL database". I asked you to clarify the specific DBMS you're using (MySQL or Access), both of which use SQL to query and manipulate data. If you want us to help you, you need to provide **specific** information, especially when someone directly asks to you clarify something. Otherwise, you're wasting both your time and ours.

Comment: @VMai I am using Open office SQL View to query. The database has been moved to SQL

Comment: SQL is a language, not a platform.  Access and MySQL are platforms.  Which platform are you querying?

Comment: As Ken White stated, there's no such thing as a "SQL database". Could it be MS SQL server? How's your OpenOffice connected to your database?

Comment: @VMai I used open office to create a new database that is connected to an access database. the filetype for the new database is .odb, does this answer the question? I am not quite sure how to determine the 'platform'.

Comment: Then you probably used an ODBC data source and the backend is still Access.

Comment: @VMai does this mean my platform is Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM PHAII01 
WHERE DATE = #02/11/13 12:00 AM#
```

or like this

```
SELECT *
FROM PHAII01 
WHERE DATE = CDate('02/11/13 12:00 AM')
```

Comment: The first worked great! The second returned an error:'The data content could not be loaded'

Comment: @VegasFun Right, I always forget that MS-Access doesn't support the SQL Standard converion fucntion. Try the `CDate(..)` function instead. (I will change my answer to that)

Answer (score 0):

With that queries all will return errors, since `date` is a function of MySQL.

You can access a date by 'yyyy-dd-mm' so '2013-02-11' will work to see if a date is that specific date.

But if you have a `datetime` field you have to do `DATE(myfield) = '2013-02-11'`.

Comment: `DATE` is no [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. As OP stated his column is actually named `DATE`, so this part should not provoke an error in MySQL. But I don't think that the OP is using MySQL at all.

Comment: He should have use `\`` around the DATE column. Otherwise you do get an error. At least I do.

Comment: I don't, see [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16305/2). I usually don't use such a confusing column name myself.

Answer (score 0):

I have to format() the values in the DATE column to better fit the query.

**This had achieved the desired results**

```
SELECT *
FROM PHAII01 
WHERE format(DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2013-02-11'
```